# HTML code works on desktop but does not work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, scss-mixins

```
<div class="summ_info" data-priority="2">
    <BubbleContent Data="@ViewModel.BubbleContent">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="icon_hover"></div>
    </BubbleContent>

    <Bubble Data="@ViewModel.BubbleContent" BubblePosition="right" TrianglePosition="top">
        <div>"Content"</div>
    </Bubble>
</div>
```

```
.dfinfo {
    @if($is-mobile) {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    @else {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

    & > span {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .summ_info {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;

        .BubbleContent {
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: inherit;
            width: inherit;
            padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: block;

            .icon{
                height: inherit;
                width: inherit;
                background-image: url(###);
                background-size: contain;
                display: block;
            }

            .icon_hover {
                height: 0px;
                width: 0px;
                background-image: url(###);
                background-size: contain;
            }

            &:hover .icon_hover {
                height: inherit;
                width: inherit;
            }

            &:hover .icon {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a piece of legacy code below, and it works perfectly on desktop. But I am not able to render it on mobile.

Can you point in the right direction about what mistake I am making?

I have removed the url inside url(), but that is correct in the real code since it works on desktop.

Thanks.

Comment: *But I am not able to render it on mobile.* What do you mean by this? What issues do you face?

Comment: It seems that the issue might be related to the CSS media queries. The CSS code you provided seems to include some media queries that are supposed to adjust the styles for mobile devices, but it's not clear whether the `$is-mobile` variable is being set correctly.

Comment: @kiner_shah The ```.sum_info``` css (and everything under it) is not getting rendered on mobile. It is getting rendered on desktop. The "is-mobile" is set correctly.

Comment: @Haminteu The "is-mobile" is set correctly. But the ".sum_info" div+css is not working on mobile.